# How to remove successive similar numbers in a pandas DF column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a pandas DF with a column - this column can have 3 values, either 0, 1 or ' ' (see example below).
What I want to do is remove all successive **numbers** that are similar. So a 0 can never be followed by a 0 and a 1 can never be followed by 1. Instead I want to replace these by a ' '.

**Current pandas DF**

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1:00 | 0 |
| 2:00 |  |
| 3:00 | 0 |
| 4:00 | 1 |
| 5:00 |  |
| 6:00 |  |
| 7:00 | 1 |
| 8:00 | 1 |
| 9:00 | 0 |

**What I want**

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1:00 | 0 |
| 2:00 |  |
| 3:00 |  |
| 4:00 | 1 |
| 5:00 |  |
| 6:00 |  |
| 7:00 |  |
| 8:00 |  |
| 9:00 | 0 |

I tried to work with loops, but cannot find a clean way to refer to 'the next same value'.
Any simple solution for this?

Comment: In output 3:00 should also have 0 then since it is after empty string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `itertools` solution:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

df.value = list(chain.from_iterable(
                          [key, *['']*(len(list(gr))-1)]
                          for key, gr in groupby(df.value.replace("", np.nan).ffill())
                      )
           )
```

- `replace`ing empty strings with `np.nan`
- `f`orward `fill`ing the `NaN`s to get streams of 0's and 1's
- `group`ing `by` 0's and 1's
- placing back the `key` (which is 0 or 1) along with some empty strings (group's length - 1)
- flattening these blocks with `chain.from_iterable`
- casting to a `list` to assign it back to the dataframe

to get

```
   time value
0  1:00     0
1  2:00
2  3:00
3  4:00     1
4  5:00
5  6:00
6  7:00
7  8:00
8  9:00     0
```

Comment: That's great use of `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `loc` on `value` to drop the rows having empty strings, then `shift` and compare the filtered rows to create a boolean mask, next `mask` the values with empty string where the boolean mask holds True

```
s = df['value'].loc[lambda x: x != '']
m = s.eq(s.shift())
df.loc[m[m].index, 'value'] = ''
```

---

```
   time value
0  1:00   0
1  2:00      
2  3:00      
3  4:00   1
4  5:00      
5  6:00      
6  7:00      
7  8:00      
8  9:00   0
```